# Is there a way to use a field's value in the Model to set a style attribute dynamically?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I have created a CSHTML email template file to send alerts when a specific event is about to end (i.e. sends an alert 10-minutes before end, then at 5-minutes before end, etc.).  I want to highlight the type of event (since there can be more than one) by color to differentiate the messages.  What I currently have is this:

```
<strong style="color: {event color}">@alert.event</strong> is scheduled to end: <strong>@endEasternTime
```

I would like to be able to set the *{event color}* based on the value in **@alert.event**, but I'm not sure that I can.  I tried to create a script in the file, but I'm not sure how to get its return value into the style tag:

```
<script>
    // Get the root element
    var r = document.querySelector(':root');

    // Create a function for getting a variable value
    function getEventColor(event) {
        // Get the styles (properties and values) for the root
        var rs = getComputedStyle(r);

        // Get the color associated with the event (default is the border color)
        return (event === "event1"
            ? rs.getPropertyValue('--evt1Color')
            : (event === "event2"
                ? rs.getPropertyValue('--evt2Color')
                : (event === "event3"
                    ? rs.getPropertyValue('--evt3Color')
                    : rs.getPropertyValue('--bdrColor')
                    )
                )
            );
    }
</script>
```

Note that I have created HTML variables in the file to match up the colors to other styles in the file (such as *border-color*) -- for space considerations and clarity, I'm not going to show that here.

Is there a way to do this?  If not using the inline CSS above, can I update a ****class**** or ****id**** on the fly using something like the *script* method above and, if so, what's the best way.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use if else..

```@if (@alert.event == value1) {
    <strong class= "color1">
else if  (@alert.event == value2){
    <strong class= "color2">
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use if.. else..

```
@if (@alert.event == value1) 
{     
     <strong class="color1">
}
else if (@alert.event == value2)
{     
    <strong class="color2"> 
}
else {
    <strong class="colorn">
}
```

Or simpler way could be naming the classes based on your event and adding color using CSS.

```
<strong class="event @alert.event">
```

The  tag has 2 classes (event and the value generated)

Lets say `@alert.event = "test"`, then add the CSS to the class as shown below.

```
.event.test {
    color: <color code>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Akash, I tried your "simpler way" and it worked like a charm!  Thank you... that's bugged me for a while.

Comment: @MarkLinebarger No problem Mark!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I have ten events and five of them should have the same color, how would I group the five?  Or will I have to set up each class separately (as you show in the ".event.test" exampel above)?

Comment: You can set the color to all the events in one line if you want. 
`.event.test1, .event.test2, .event.test3 { color: <color code> }`

Comment: Got it... thanks again.  I missed the comma(,) separator.  I appreciate all your help!